# Solving Recurrence Relation of $T(n)=4T(n-2)+2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

### Question

> Solve Recurrence Relation of $T(n)=4T(n-2)+2$
>
> Base case-: $T(1)=1,T(2)=2$

### My Approach/solution

$$T(n)=4T(n-2)+2$$
$$T(n-2)=4T(n-4)+2 \tag{1}$$
$$T(n-4)=4T(n-6)+2 \tag{2}$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ in my equation
$$\begin{align*}
T(n)&=4\cdot (4T(n-4)+2)+2\\
&=4^{2}\cdot T(n-2\cdot 2)+2\cdot 4^{1}+2\cdot 4^{0}\\
&=4^{2}\cdot(4T(n-6)+2)+2\cdot 4^{1}+2\cdot 4^{0}\\
&=4^{3}\cdot T(n-2\cdot 3)+2\cdot 4^{2}+2\cdot 4^{1}+2\cdot 4^{0}\\
\vdots \\
&=4^{k}\cdot T(n-2\cdot k)+2\cdot 4^{k-1}+...+2\cdot 4^{2}+2\cdot 4^{1}+2\cdot 4^{0}
\end{align*}$$

Substituing  $T(n-2\cdot k)$ by $2$, i.e $T(2)=2$
$$n-2\cdot k=2 \Rightarrow k=\frac{n-2}{2}$$

So our equation will look like

$$\begin{align*}
T(n)&=2\cdot 4^{k}+2\cdot 4^{k-1}+...+2\cdot 4^{2}+2\cdot 4^{1}+2\cdot 4^{0}\\
T(n)&=2\cdot \left(4^{0}+4^{1}+4^{2}+...+4^{k-1}+4^{k}\right)\\
T(n)&=2\cdot \left(4^{0}\cdot \frac{(4^{k+1}-1)}{4-1}\right)
\end{align*}$$

$k=\frac{n-2}{2}$

$$\begin{align*}
T(n)&=2\cdot \left(\frac{(4^{k+1}-1)}{4-1}\right)\\
T(n)&=2\cdot \frac{2^{n}-1}{3}
\end{align*}$$

Is it correct? Also if it is correct, can anyone hint me another approach as it is bit lengthy.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the $T(n)$ you have found applies only to $n$ even

Comment: $$T(1)=2\cdot \frac{2-1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}\neq 1$$

Comment: $T(n)=4T(n-2)+2$ has characteristic polynomial $x^2-4=0$ and constant nonhomogenous part.  The characteristic polynomial factors as $(x+2)(x-2)=0$.  This implies that the closed form solution will be of the form $T(n)=c_1\cdot 2^n+c_2\cdot (-2)^n+d$ where $c_1,c_2,d$ are constants that can be solved for given initial conditions.

Comment: i forgot to mention , it will work for $n=\text{even case}$

Comment: Hint: let $a_n=T_n+\frac{2}{3}$. Then $a_n=4a_{n-2}$ is a geometric progression.

Comment: @JMoravitz $d$ must satisfy $d=4d+2$, i.e. $d=-\frac{2}{3}$. $c_1$, $c_2$ can be found with $T(1), T(2)$.

Comment: @laura are you familiar with generating functions or willing to learn how to apply them?

Comment: @rtybase i will be glad to learn

Answer (score 1):

Using [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) technique we have 
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}T(n)\cdot x^n=T_0+1\cdot x+2\cdot x^2+\sum\limits_{n=3}T(n)\cdot x^n=\\
T_0+1\cdot x+2\cdot x^2+\sum\limits_{n=3}\left(4T(n-2)+2\right)\cdot x^n=\\
T_0+4\sum\limits_{n=3}T(n-2)\cdot x^n + x + 2\cdot x^2 +\sum\limits_{n=3}2\cdot x^n=\\
T_0+4x^2\sum\limits_{n=3}T(n-2)\cdot x^{n-2}-2-x+\sum\limits_{n=0}2\cdot x^n=\\
T_0+4x^2\sum\limits_{n=1}T(n)\cdot x^{n}-2-x+\sum\limits_{n=0}2\cdot x^n=\\
T_0-4T_0x^2-2-x+4x^2\sum\limits_{n=0}T(n)\cdot x^{n}   +\sum\limits_{n=0}2\cdot x^n=\\
T_0-4T_0x^2-2-x+4x^2f(x)+ \frac{2}{1-x}$$
or
$$f(x)=T_0-\frac{2+x}{1-4x^2}+\frac{2}{(1-x)(1-4x^2)}=\\
T_0-\left( \frac{5}{4(1-2x)}+\frac{3}{4(1+2x)} \right)+\left(-\frac{2}{3(1-x)}+\frac{2}{1-2x}+\frac{2}{3(1+2x)} \right)=\\
T_0-\frac{2}{3(1-x)}+\frac{3}{4(1-2x)}-\frac{1}{12(1+2x)}=\\
T_0-\frac{2}{3}\sum\limits_{n=0}x^n+\frac{3}{4}\sum\limits_{n=0}(2x)^n-\frac{1}{12}\sum\limits_{n=0}(-2x)^n=\\
T_0+\frac{2}{3}\sum\limits_{n=0}\left(\frac{3}{4}\cdot 2^n -\frac{1}{12}\cdot (-2)^n-\frac{2}{3}\right)x^n$$
or
$$T(n)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot 2^n -\frac{1}{12}\cdot (-2)^n-\frac{2}{3}, n\geq 1$$
or 
$$T(n)=\frac{1}{12}\left(9\cdot 2^n + (-1)^{n+1}\cdot 2^n-8\right)$$
as presented by **Dr. Sonnhard Graubner**, only with a complete proof this time. The result is easy to validate $T(1)=1, T(2)=2, T(3)=6$.

Some of the shortcuts are explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Examples_of_generating_functions_for_simple_sequences).

More learning materials [here](http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=355).

Answer (score 0):

i think the right solution is given by $$T(n)=\frac{1}{12} \left(9\ 2^n+(-1)^{n+1} 2^n-8\right)$$
at first solve the equation $$T(n)=4T(n-2)$$ with $$T(n)=q^n$$

Comment: sir is my solution wrong?

Comment: How did you find this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This is a linear second order recurrence equation. You can solve it with methods similar to solution methods for differential equations. Note thate recurrence equations are sometimes called difference equations, because they are the discrete form of differential equations. Notice that the generating functions method (as provided in the other answers) is also nothing else than the power series method used for differential equations.

The general solution is given as a superposition of the solution of

$$T_h(n+2)=4T_h(n)$$

which is the homogeneous equation and the particular solution. The homogeneous solution can be obtained by an exponential ansatz $T_h(n)= A^n$. Note you will get two solutions for $A$. They should be $A_{1,2}=\pm 2$.

Then find the particular solution by using the method of undetermined coefficients. Ansatz is a constant $T_p(n)=c=\text{const.}$. You should obtain $T_p(n)=-2/3$.

The general solution is given by:

$$T(n)=c_1A_1^n+ c_2A_2^n+(-2/3).$$

Determine the “constants of integration” $c_{1,2}$ by using your “initial values” for $T(1)$ and $T(2)$.