# How do I solve the non-homogeneous recurrence relation $f(n) = f(n-3) +1$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

This is part of a question from my combinatorics homework I've been trying to solve for a few days now...
The initial conditions are: f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1
I tried first to solve the homogeneous part by guessing. My result is $f(n)= \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor$ but I need to show a formal calculation, and I'm not really sure how to do it. 
I'm also not sure how to use the solution to the homogeneous recurrence in order to find the solution to the non-homogeneous relation given.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have any initial conditions?

Comment: I think this can not be done without a first value.

Comment: @Samorales more than missing the first value, it is missing the first *three* values, all three of which will be important in the final expression.  One could I suppose come up with the expression where all three appear as variables, but unless if this is necessary, why bother

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention them. edited

Comment: There are [plenty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497376/resolving-tn-9tn-21-and-tn-tn-4/) of [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466134/solving-recurrence-relation-of-tn-4tn-22/) on MSE.

Answer (score 3):

From your initial conditions, I think you meant $f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac n3\right\rfloor+1$.

---

**A Difference Equation Approach**

Using the shift operator on sequences $Sf(n)=f(n+1)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\left(I-S^{-3}\right)f(n)\tag1\\
&=\left(I+S^{-1}+S^{-2}\right)(I-S^{-1})f(n)\tag2\\
&=\color{#00F}{\left(I-\omega^{-1}S^{-1}\right)}\color{#090}{\left(I-\omega S^{-1}\right)}\color{#C00}{\left(I-S^{-1}\right)}f(n)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
$(1)$: original equation; $1=f(n)-f(n-3)$
$(2)$: this shows that $n\mapsto3$, so $f(n)=\frac13n$ is a solution
$(3)$: full factorization, with $\omega=e^{i2\pi/3}$, to get the homogeneous part

Therefore, using [Linear Difference Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation), we get the general solution to be
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)
&=\frac13n+\color{#C00}{c_1}+\color{#090}{c_2\omega^n}+\color{#00F}{c_3\omega^{-n}}\tag4\\
&=\frac13n+c_1+c_4\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right)+c_5\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Now we just need to compute $c_1$, $c_4$, and $c_5$ from the initial conditions $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1$, which gives
$$
f(n)=\frac13n+\frac23+\frac13\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}3\right)+\frac1{3\sqrt3}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}3\right)\tag6
$$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the recursive relation, we get
\begin{align}
f(n) &= f\left(3\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor+n\bmod 3\right) \\
&= f\left(3\left[\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor-1\right]+n\bmod 3\right)+1 \\
&= f\left(3\left[\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor-2\right]+n\bmod 3\right)+2 \\
&\vdots\\
&=f\left(n\bmod 3\right) +\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right\rfloor+1,
\end{align}
where we use the initial condition because $(n \bmod 3)\in\{0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- solve characteristic equation $r^3=1$
- solutions are $f(n)=a1^n+bj^n+cj^{2n}$
- RHS$=1$ is a root so find a particular solution of degree +1, that is $\alpha n$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$f(3)=f(0)+1$$
$$f(6)=f(3)+1=f(0)+2$$
and so by induction, $f(3n)=f(0)+n=n+1$

Similarly, $f(3n+1)=n+1$ and $f(3n+2)=n+1$

Now to unite the arguement, we can say that 
$$x \in \{3n,3n+1,3n+2\} \implies \left\lfloor \frac{x}{3} \right\rfloor = n$$
Thus, $f(x)=\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3} \right\rfloor + 1$
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{0} = \mrm{f}\pars{1} = \mrm{f}\pars{2} = 1}$:
$$
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{n}z^{n}} =
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{n - 3}z^{n} +
\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty}z^{n}}
$$
$$  
\underbrace{-\mrm{f}\pars{0} - \mrm{f}\pars{1}z -\mrm{f}\pars{2}z^{2}}
_{\ds{-1 - z - z^{2}}}\ +\
\underbrace{\overbrace{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{n}z^{n}}
^{\ds{\equiv\ \mathcal{F}\pars{z}}}}
_{\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{n} = \bracks{z^{n}}\mathcal{F}\pars{z}}}
 =
z^{3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{n}z^{n} + {z^{3} \over 1 - z}
$$

---

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\pars{z} & = {1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}\pars{1 + z + z^{2}}} =
{1 \over \pars{1 - z}\pars{1 - z^{3}}} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}z^{i + 3j}
\\[5mm]
\mrm{f}\pars{n} & =
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{i + 3j = n} =
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{i = n - 3j} =
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{n - 3j \geq 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{j \leq {n \over 3}} =
\sum_{j = 0}^{\left\lfloor\,{n/3}\,\right\rfloor}1
\implies\bbx{\mrm{f}\pars{n} =
\left\lfloor\,{n \over 3}\,\right\rfloor + 1}
\\ &
\end{align}

[image]